# Analytics Params being truncated on Product URLs - Magento CE 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics, 301-redirect

In Magento 1.9.1 Community Edition when adding params to the end of the URL they get truncated. My concern is that when tracking campaigns the tracking parameters get truncated. Has anyone else experienced this behavior and come up with a solution to preserve UTM params to Magento product pages?

Comment: I don't think it is truncating, instead I think you are getting a redirect. In your htaccess rewrite you could look to changing it to something like RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

Comment: You're correct it was being redirected. It turns out the CreareSEO was redirecting on product pages and therefore truncating the params. Disabling the product redirect in the extension resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the CreareSEO 1.2.0 extension was redirecting on product pages and therefore truncating the params in the redirect. Disabling the product redirect in the extension resolved the issue.